# How do I add space to my math fraction

Tags: math-mode

I am using math to create fractions. But with indices it kinda looks crammed. Example:

[image]

Code:

```
$\eta = \frac{U_{OC}I_{SC}FF}{P_L}$
```

Can I somehow add vertical space around the fraction bar?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Do you need it be inline math?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your equation would look better in a display-math environment. Do you have to use inline math?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\raisebox` to move it up.  Here is a before and after comparison:

[image]

But you really should consider using display mode which produces good results with the math on its own line.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Inline:
$\eta = \frac{U_{OC}I_{SC}FF}{P_L} = \frac{\raisebox{0.15ex}{$\scriptstyle U_{OC}I_{SC}FF$}}{P_L}$

\medskip
With display math:
\[ \eta = \frac{U_{OC}I_{SC}FF}{P_L} \]
\end{document}
```